# MySQL group by column and set variable if one row contains a specific value

Tags: mysql

Say I have the following table:

```
Type        |Ownership         
-------------------------
Drill       | owned
Drill       | owned
Plant       | owned
Plant       | rental
Light Plant | owned
Light Plant | owned
Light Plant | owned
Light Plant | rental
```

I would like to group these by Type only, and if a single record of a Type contains ownership = "rental" display ownership as "rental

So this is the result I want:

```
Type        |Ownership         
-------------------------
Drill       | owned
Plant       | rental
Light Plant | rental
```

What I've done:

```
SELECT Type, Ownership
FROM table
GROUP BY Type, Ownership
```

Of course this results in getting multiple records of a Type (if this type has two kinds of ownerships)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo: http://rextester.com/EAAGP39848

```
SELECT Type, IF(SUM(Ownership = 'rental'), 'rental', 'owned') AS Ownership2
  FROM type_ownership
  GROUP BY Type;
```

Inspired from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30285287/1435132

Edit (explanation):

```
SELECT *, Ownership = 'rental' AS isRental FROM type_ownership;
```

isRental is 1 when Ownership = rental

```
SELECT Type, SUM(Ownership = 'rental') AS sumRental, IF(SUM(Ownership = 'rental'), 'rental', 'owned') AS Ownership2
FROM type_ownership
GROUP BY Type;
```

Here `sumRental` is count of records where ownership is rental in that type.

Hence, `IF(SUM(Ownership = 'rental'), 'rental', 'owned')` returns `rental` if sum is greater than 0 i.e. any ownership is rental.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. How does this work? I don't understand the SUM() in this context

Comment: Added explanation. @BerryJones

Answer (score 0):

You can try a query like this:

```
SELECT
    mytype
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(ownership ORDER BY IF(ownership='rental',1,2)), ',', 1)
FROM OWNER
GROUP BY MYTYPE;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> select * from owner;
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | mytype      | ownership |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | Drill       | owned     |
|  2 | Drill       | owned     |
|  3 | Plant       | owned     |
|  4 | Plant       | rental    |
|  5 | Light Plant | owned     |
|  6 | Light Plant | owned     |
|  7 | Light Plant | owned     |
|  8 | Light Plant | rental    |
+----+-------------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT
    ->     mytype
    ->     , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(ownership ORDER BY IF(ownership='rental',1,2)), ',', 1)
    -> FROM owner
    -> GROUP BY mytype;
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| mytype      | SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(ownership ORDER BY IF(ownership='rental',1,2)), ',', 1) |
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Drill       | owned                                                                                 |
| Light Plant | rental                                                                                |
| Plant       | rental                                                                                |
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

Query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM demo
 WHERE type NOT IN ( SELECT type FROM demo
                      WHERE ownership = 'rental'
                      GROUP BY type )
UNION

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM demo
 WHERE ownership = 'rental'
 GROUP BY type;
```